# ItunesConnect : in-app purchase product won't update on ITC after a successful upload

Tags: xcode, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, itmstransporter

My issue concerns update of an in-app purchase product on ITC.

Since 10/21/2015 in the evening (french time), when i upload an iap through Xcode or itmsTransporter, i can't see any update on ITC.

ItmsTransporter answer me that the upload to ITC has been successful
-> BUT i can NOT see any update of the iap in the ITC web interface.

I’ve verified on ITC with several browsers with a clean cache without success.
I've also made the test with the latest version of Xcode (7.1)/Application loader (3.3), with no luck.

Since this date, the mention « An In-App Purchase has been returned and is highlighted in the table below. » appeared on my iap list page (it seems to appear also on apps without any iap)

Did any one got similar issue on updating iap ?

Many thanks

**EDIT :** After 3 days and 4 calls to Apple support USA, my issue have been resolved and i've been able to upload new content to ITC and submit my application.

This was definitely an issue on Apple side, causes by ItunesConnect update.

Comment: Same issue. Apple support is useless.

Answer (score 0):

Same here, uploaded yesterday with XCode 7.1 Application Uploader. All other IAP's in the same App work. When I try to download the content in that IAP it just stops at 6%, then the updateDownloads delegate method won't be called anymore.

The issue is also mentioned here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/23787